# How can I make this question title less clickbaity? "Weird geometry problem with very elegant result"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, titles

I recently posted a question with the title "[Weird geometry problem with very elegant result](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618734/398708)".

While this title is truthful (I explain the weirdness in the body of the question, and the result is indeed elegant), it sort of reeks of [clickbaitiness](https://edu.gcfglobal.org/en/thenow/what-is-clickbait/1/), which might annoy some users. Is this a problem, and if so, what would be a better title?

I think there is not enough space in the title box to completely and non-awkwardly express the question. If the title just gave the gist of the question, it would likely be incomprehensible and uninteresting.

I have read the [advice](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144) on question titles.

I have already accepted an answer to the question, so I may or may not change the title based on answers here. But in any case I could use the advice in future.

Comment: I personally believe that the title of this meta post itself is clickbaity.

Comment: @mathlander Meta-clickbaity?

Comment: The OP's [Question on main Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4618734/) has been updated with a better title.

Comment: Summarize the problem in the title, and stay clear of your commentary on how the problem *made you feel*.  Your perception of weirdness and/or of "elegant result", are your subjective assessment/reactions to it.

Comment: How about "Insane geometry trick your math professor doesn't want you to know"?

Comment: @mathlander: The title of this meta post summarises its question *informatively*, which — clickbaity or not — makes it a good title, unlike the original question.

Comment: True titles can still be clickbaity. Examples: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602208/does-the-product-rule-imply-the-chain-rule https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602683/does-the-chain-rule-imply-the-product-rule

Comment: Many times when I see meta-posts about pesky things like the current one I wonder if either the enquirer is serious and has too much time on his hands or just trying to create a laughing stock... what's even funnier is that some people actually take these questions extremely seriously and write an uttermost consequential and detailed answer. IMHO questions like this are clickbaits themselves ( for reasons that just can't always be described by words ) just like most other hot meta-posts ( that's probably the reason why they're "hot" in the first placed - because they're clickbaits ).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Titles are supposed to be objective and informative, among other things. Your problem is about approximately finding the value of a parameter for a line to be tangent to three circles, which is a bit of a mouthful, but you can try something like *"How to approximate a parameter that gives a tangent line to three circles?"* or something along those lines. Your current title is subjective and uninformative: why is it a weird problem? Why is the solution elegant? I am not sure, and you should definitely pick a better one.

Also, why not use a more faithful image as in the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618734/weird-geometry-problem-with-very-elegant-result#comment9739880_4618734)?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. About the faithfulness of the image: I would say that the image I used is faithful, given the size of the earth. The image by itself is misleading, so I clarified it in the question ("the ground is actually a circular arc of the earth").

Comment: I just realized, the faithfulness of my image depends on the unit for distance (if the unit is metres, it's faithful; it the unit is 1000 km, not faithful).